# How to use different values for CC depending on goal in gnumake

Tags: gnu-make

I have one code base that I'd like to use to make two different "goals"
One required that I compile with g++ (we use gtest for a unit test target), the other needs gcc4 our deleivered code is ANSI C.

I'm trying to use the target specific variables of gnu make to acheive this

so I have

```
unit_test_target: CC=g++
unit_test_target: unit_test_pre-reqs
    recipe
```

and

```
lab_target:CC=gcc4
lab_target: lab_pre_reqs
    recipe
```

The CC variable does not seem to get used in making the pre-reqs which I have found an explanation for.  But I'm not seeing how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Collins

More details...

TESTSUBDIRS = dir1 dir1/testing dir2 dir2/testing

.PHONY: testsubdirs $(TESTSUBDIRS)

testsubdirs : $(TESTSUBDIRS)

$(TESTSUBDIRS) : objdir
    $(MAKE) -e -C $@

objdir: $(CSPLATFORMDIR)/makebuilddir
    $(CSPLATFORMDIR)/makebuilddir $(BUILDDIR)

LAB4DIRS = dir1 dir2
.PHONY: t100lab4dirs $(LAB4DIRS)

lab4dirs : $(LAB4DIRS)

$(T100LAB4SDIRS) : objdir
    $(MAKE)  -e -C $@

gtest: CC=g++
gtest:  $(CSPLATFORMDIR)/makebuilddir $(TESTSUBDIRS)
    $(CSPLATFORMDIR)/makebuilddir $(BUILDDIR)
    $(AR) -r $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
    ls -l $(TARGET)
    g++ -I$(BUILDDIR)/.. -I$(BUILDDIR)../../inc -I$(GTESTINC) $(BUILDDIR)/*.o -lpthread $(GTESTDIR)/make/gtest_main.a -o $(BUILDDIR)/gtest

lab_target.a:CC=gcc4
lab_target.a: $(CSPLATFORMDIR)/makebuilddir $(T100LAB4DIRS)
    $(CSPLATFORMDIR)/makebuilddir $(BUILDDIR)
    $(AR) -r $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
    ls -l $(TARGET)

Comment: Please show the rules for your `pre-reqs` targets.

Comment: You have two separate _pre-reqs_ targets. Do they have anything in common? (If not, then you do not need target-spcific variables. Just write the rules for `unit_test_pre-reqs` to use `g++`, and then `gcc4` for `lab_pre_reqs`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU make `if` conditionals to set variables, but not based on targets.   This is normally solved by having the target that needs to use C++ to use `$(CXX)` as the compiler, and targets that need to use C use`$(CC)`.  Then set those separate variables appropriately.  I think that's also the best way.

Comment: I think you mean `$(CXX)`. In automake-land, at least, `$(CPP)` refers to the C preprocessor whereas `$(CXX)` is the C++ compiler.

Comment: Yes, a think'o. Will fix. Thanks.

Comment: Some of the same files are used in each target.  If the target is  gtest then g++ is needed to compile foo.c .  When the target is lab then gcc4 is needed to compile foo.c so I dont see yet how using different variables $(CXX) vs. $(CC) will help me here